# Cells with no apoptosis mechanism and their 'byproducts'

Tags: cancer, apoptosis

If a culture or sample of cells is such they all have no apoptosis mechanisms yet they have not been at present determined to be cancerous ; given such a cell culture is there a way to determine by their byproducts or how they signal themselves or other cells that they have no 'working' apoptosis mechanisms?

Comment: I am not sure, if I understand your question. You want to know if (or how) cells with non-functional apoptosis (however this happened) know themselves that their apoptosis is no working? And how they communicate this to other cells?

Comment: If cells with non-functioning apoptosis mechanisms can be detected by some type of test this would indicate a possible tumor as tumor cells don't have functioning apoptosis mechanisms. ( at least that's what somebody else said on this exchange)

Comment: Is there a way to test a cell or cell culture in some way simpler than analysing their genome to determine if they have actively working apoptosis mechanisms? Does a cell with a working apoptosis mechanism 'produce' or 'give off' certain signals or chemical signatures that can be detected by some 'test'?

Comment: I am not aware of any. Since apoptosis relies on signalling towards it, you can only try to trigger it and see what the outcome is. Probably nothing, that we want to try on a large scale.

Comment: Could a non-harmful virus or bacteria that normal cells could survive but would effect a cell with no apoptosis mechanism in a detectable way?

Comment: Given a specific type of cell are there certain situations like a biochemical event occuring near or adjacent to the cell that would 'normally' cause the cell to self-destruct if its apoptosis mechanisms were working. So if this biochemical event or process was artificially 'made' to occur near or at the cell's location and it didn't self-destruct it would indicate its apoptosis mechanisms were not functioning. Is this correct?

Comment: I think so, yes.

Comment: Could such an artificially induced process be used to test if certain cells or tissues are cancerous?

Comment: Can we stop discussing this in the comments and you make it a new question?